# Navigation tabs cannot insert image. How to put image as an icon in nav-tabs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm having a bit of a problem where i don't know how to adjust the nav-tabs bootstrap/css file.

I want to add an image file inside the nav-tabs and make it so that the image became an icon and have the margin-bottom be near the wording of the nav-tabs. As far as my progress goes, most of my attempts seems to have failed to achieve what I want.

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="CreditCardInfoTab">
  <li role="presentation" class="fa-sans" id="lstItemTabSaved">
    <a href="#saved" aria-controls="saved" class="lbl-credit fa-sans" role="tab" data toggle="tab">
      <i class="icon-cd" src="../Images/tab-creditcard.png">
                            <img style="margin-bottom: 0;" alt="credit/debit" />
                        </i> Pay with Saved Credit Card
    </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="fa-sans">
    <a href="#new" aria-controls="new" class="lbl-credit fa-sans" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <div class="icon-cd" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
        <img src="../Images/tab-creditcard.png" />
      </div>
      Pay with New Credit Card
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

As you can see in here ^, the saved tab tab became like that. I would appreciate any suggestion. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal was to become like this: [image]

As you can see, the icon is near towards the title, also the tab outline when click(active) become white in color and also red for the title

I've done some modification towards the css

```css
.nav-tabs>li.active>a,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #c72027;
  height: 90px;
}

.nav-tabs {
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #CCC;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
  height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="CreditCardInfoTab">

  <li role="presentation" class="fa-sans" id="lstItemTabSaved">
    <a href="#saved" aria-controls="saved" class="lbl-credit fa-sans center" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <i style="padding:5.8%; padding-bottom: 0px; margin: 0px auto; float: none; display: table;"><img style="Height: 22px; Width: 32px;" alt="credit/debit" src="../Images/tab-creditcard.png" /><br/></i>
      <div style="font-weight: 700; font-size: 12px; padding-bottom:10%">Pay with Saved Credit Card</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="fa-sans">
    <a href="#new" aria-controls="new" class="lbl-credit fa-sans" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <i style="padding:6.8%; padding-bottom: 0px; margin: 0px auto; float: none; display: table;"><img style="Height: 22px; Width: 32px;" alt="credit/debit" src="../Images/tab-creditcard.png" /><br/></i>
      <div style="font-weight: 700; font-size: 12px; padding-bottom:10%">Pay with New Credit Card</div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Its a bit of a mess since i directly apply the style towards the div

but it works and I got this:

[image]

However, if anyone can advice me on how to make my css structure more cleaner, do share. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the inserted image, I can see that this is what you want if you can change the HTML structure!

```css
img {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="CreditCardInfoTab">
  <li role="presentation" class="fa-sans" id="lstItemTabSaved">
    <a href="#saved" aria-controls="saved" class="lbl-credit fa-sans" role="tab" data toggle="tab">

      <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.newdesignfile.com%2Fpostpic%2F2013%2F08%2Fcredit-card-icon_363389.png&f=1&nofb=1" style="margin-bottom: 0;" alt="credit/debit" />
      <p>Pay with Saved Credit Card</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation" class="fa-sans">
    <a href="#new" aria-controls="new" class="lbl-credit fa-sans" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">

      <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.newdesignfile.com%2Fpostpic%2F2013%2F08%2Fcredit-card-icon_363389.png&f=1&nofb=1" />
      <p>Pay with New Credit Card</p>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Toan. Thanks for replying. I've tried your way and it works as shown in the code snippet. But, the goal is to make the icon be near as possible towards the title. I've posted my answer below but its a bit of a mess. If you can advice me on how to clean it up that would be great. Cheers!

Comment: HI @ImanManan Can you update the example with your current css? I run your snippet but the result is not really as the image.